# Join Server 2012 R2 to existing Server 2008 R2 Foundation domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

Is it possible to make a server running Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard a member server of an existing domain running on a Server 2008 R2 **Foundation** Edition server?

According to [Introduction to Windows Server 2008 Foundation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd459191(v=ws.10).aspx) on TechNet:

> In the Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation operating system, the server must be a member of a workgroup or, if joined to a domain, joined at the root of the forest as a member server or domain controller.

This *implies* that other non-Foundation servers can be part of the same domain, but can anyone confirm this is true before I instruct a client to purchase the server license?

Comment: I shouldn't even have to ask a question like this, but these oddball editions of Windows Servers seem to have all sorts of gotchas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a member server to a domain that is using a Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation as its DC and "primary" server.

To "try before you buy" and eliminate the worry of burning money, you can [download a free evaluation copy of Windows Server 2012 R2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2012-r2) and then purchase a product key after you confirm that it works.